# XSLT transformation not retaining the attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

We have the following XML that we need to find and replace the path in src attribute parameters

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ul>
<font> test sample font test </font>
<img src="/assets/rep/myimage.png"> test</img>
<img src="/assets/rep/myimage.png" height="20px"> test</img>
</ul>
```

My XSLT is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- remove disallowed elements but keep its children -->
    <xsl:template match="font">
        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@src">
        <xsl:variable name="imagesrc" select="replace(.,'/assets/rep/','/images/')"/>    
        <img src="{$imagesrc}" />
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT rendition works for

```
<img src="/assets/rep/myimage.png"> test</img>
```

but not for

```
<img src="/assets/rep/myimage.png" height="20px"> test</img>
```

I tried to add match="@src[parent::img]" but that does not work either. Can you let me know what I am missing in my XSLT to retain the attributes and ONLY modify "src" attributes?

Comment: Is your XSLT complete? You don't have a template matching `img` and as a consequence the built-in templates will be used for that node, which which will select the child nodes, but not any attributes (and so your template matching `@src` would not be used).

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Or just not the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your current *logic* to templates like this:

```
...
<xsl:template match="img">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img/@src">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'/assets/rep/','/images/')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
...
```

In your try, you created an element `<img>` while your context-node is an attribute `@src`. With the provided example you will be fine!

Comment: The above worked. Thanks. I also added a case insensitive lookup with 'i' flag as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="@src">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'/assets/rep/','/images/')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```