# XSLT to find and replace attributes while retaining the rest of the tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

We have the following XML that we need to find and replace the path in src attribute parameters

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ul>
      <img src="/assets/myimage.png"/>
    </ul>
```

Following is my XSLT in 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="globalReplace">
        <xsl:param name="outputString"/>
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($outputString,$target)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($outputString,$target),$replacement)" />
                <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="substring-after($outputString,$target)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$outputString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@src">
        <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
            <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="target" select="'/assets/'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="'/images/'"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*">
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Issue 1**
I get the following result when we perform the conversion

```
<img>/images/myimage.png</img>
```

instead of

```
<img src="/images/myimage.png"/>
```

**Issue 2**

The XSLT transformation is not retaining attributes like

```
<img src="/images/myimage.png" height="20"/>
```

I had a solution provided for XSLT2.0 but could not find any references. Thanks in advance!

[XSLT transformation not retaining the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797073/xslt-transformation-not-retaining-the-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make replacement a bit more easier in **globalReplace** template and put in match as `@src[parent::img]`, please see XSL below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="globalReplace">
        <xsl:param name="param.str"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.target"/>
        <xsl:param name="param.replacement"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($param.str, $param.target)">                    
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($param.str, $param.target), $param.replacement, substring-after($param.str, $param.target))"/>              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$param.str"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@src[parent::img]">                
        <xsl:attribute name="src">                    
            <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.str" select="."/>                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.target" select="'/assets/'"/>                       
                <xsl:with-param name="param.replacement" select="'/images/'"/>                   
            </xsl:call-template>               
        </xsl:attribute>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then your result will be:

```
<ul>
    <img src="/images/myimage.png"/>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a copy-template defining an exception to the `@src` template:

```
<xsl:template match="img/@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This retains the `img` tags with its attributes in their original state.